Do Operating Expenses typically include Depreciation & Amortization?
I have been finding conflicting information on the internet regarding whether depreciation and amortization (D&A) is part of operating expenses.
On the Income Statement page on Wikipedia, D&A is considered to be part of operating expenses.
On the Operating Profit page on Investopedia, D&A is not included as part of operating expenses when calculating the formula for Operating Profit
For the sake of consistent terminology and language, is it more conventional for one to include D&A under operating expenses or not

Not terribly relevant for this site, however I'll quickly note that accounting standards will differ by industry. In CPG manufacturing, for example, it's probably accurate to assume that most D&A ends up in cost of sales (and thus, contained within "Operating Income", but before the separate line "Operating Expenses" that decreases from Gross Margin.

I assume "D&A" refers to "depreciation and amortization".  But it would be helpful to spell out the acronym the first time you use it.

What is a relevant stackexchange to post similar questions to?

It is generally considered an "Operating Expense" in the sense that it represents the "cost" of using assets to operate the business. The alternative would be a "non-operating" expense, which would not make sense since it's definitely related to ongoing operations.
Investopedia often contains semantic contradictions when defining financial terms - it seems that in their formula for "Operating Profit" they are considering "Operating Expense" to be the actual tangible expenses when operating a company, and account for D&A separately to calculate Operating Profit. Since Depreciation is a non-tangible, non-cash expense, one could argue that it's not a true expense required to operate the business since it's not cash out the door (like payroll, advertising, etc.), but a necessary "expense" to balance the drop in value of an operating asset over time.  At some point, the business is going to have to replace those assets that are dropping in value, and D&A help spread that "cost" over the life of the asset.
Since they are included in "Operating Profit", which would just be Operating Revenue less Operating Expense, it would make more sense to me to include D&A in Operating Expense - it's not clear why that Investopedia article breaks it out separately.  In fact, one Investopedia page on Operating Expense does include D&A, while another does not (at least not explicitly).

Amortization just spreads the purchase price across multiple years, so yes, it's an operating expense. Depreciation is just the process of recognizing that things lose value as they wear out; if the value of equipment inventory went onto the books (which for Capital equipment it should), this is how it gets taken back off the books.
